# Using tidy-html5 with inline styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, email

I am using tidy-html5 to fix up the code for my email builds. For those that dont know email used inline styling. The issue is that it does this:

`<a href=
   "www.randomwebsitehere.com"
   style=
        "text-decoration: none;"></a>`

While this is being red properly, it causes an issue with tracking. Is there anyway to prevent tidy-html5 from doing this line break?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the default text wrap on tidy-html5 is 68. Since tags with inline styling are wayyyy long, some over 400 characters in my case, I just changed the options like so:

`option = {
  "wrap":400
}`